# Reading and writing a file with special characters in c

Tags: c, file, character

Using the C language, I am trying to manipulate some files generated by openssl and containing a lot of (very) special characters. But the end of file seems to be prematurely detected.
For example see an extract of my program, that is supposed to copy a file to another :

(for simplicity reasons I do not show the test of the opening of the file but I do that in my program)

```
char msgcrypt[FFILE];
FILE* fMsg = fopen(f4Path,"r");
while(fgets(tmp,FFILE,fMsg) != NULL) strcat(msgcrypt,tmp);
fclose(fMsg);
FILE* fMsg2 = fopen(f5Path,"w");
fprintf(fMsg2,"%s",msgcrypt);
fclose(fMsg2);
```

here is the content of the file located at f4Path :

```
Salted__X¢~xÁïÈú™xe^„ﬂ¯�˜<åD
```

now the content of the file located at f5Path :

```
Salted__X¢~xÁïÈú™xe^„ﬂ¯
```

Notice that 4 characters are missing.

Do someone have an idea?

Comment: Consider using fopen(f4path,"rb") and fread() for reading non printable characters, otherwise known as binary characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But the end of file seems to be prematurely detected

Sounds familiar.

- Use `fopen(f4Path, "rb")` when opening the file. This has real significance on Windows.
- Don't use string functions (`fprintf`, `strcat`, `fgets` etc) they will choke on `NUL` characters. Use `fread` and `fwrite` instead.

Comment: thank you ! do you think that I will have the same problem when I use the functions write and read with some socket ?

Comment: I ask that because I have the same kind of problem when I use these functions to communicate through sockets, but I am not sure that the problem is from there

Comment: Now my problem seems to be fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`strcat` tries and copy a nul-terminated `char *`. Which means, if it encounters a 0, which it probably has done here, it will stop copying.

You'd better use `open` `read`, `memcpy` and `write`.

Comment: You can't use read and write on `FILE*`, so you'd have to open the file using `open` instead of `fopen`.

Answer (score 1):

That character it stops on I copied into a hex editor, and it ends up being EF BF BD, a BOM if I'm not mistaken. As a result, reading the file as a text file fails. I don't see any NULL characters (unless copying and pasting got rid of them).

The answer (as has already been discussed) is to not treat it as a text file, and avoiding the str functions won't do any harm either.

The first thing I'd do though is add a check for how may characters are read, that way you'll know where the data is being truncated. Right now it could be in any of: read, strcat, write.